# How to calculate the number of pixels used when aggregating in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have two binary files with (1440*720) the same dimensions: I want to take the average of my first file based on the  the second file values (intervals),the values of this file range from 1 to 7. whenever the values in the second file range between 0-1, calculate the corresponding average in the first file and return the result,do the same thing with 2-3,3-4,5-6,7-8.no data values are assigned as NA.

1- to read the first file :

```
conne <- file("C:\\corr.bin","rb")
corr <- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4, n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
#please assume a matrix of 720*1440 dimnsions
```

2- to read the second file :

```
conne1 <- file("C:\\use.bin","rb")
cus <- readBin(conne1, numeric(), size=4, n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
#please assume a matrix of 720*1440 dimnsions
```

calculate:

```
cusBREAK <- cut(cus,1:8))
aggregate(corr, list(cusBREAK), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

This worked fine But I need also to know the number of pixels used and also the percentage  out of the total number of pixels.

```
  Results 
  Group.1   x    number of pixels    percentage (out of the total number of pixcels)
 1   (0,1] 0.5      ?                       ?
 2   (1,2] 0.23     ?                       ?
 3   (2,3] 0.65     ?                       ?
 4   (3,4] 0.3      ?                       ?
 5   (4,5] 0.36
```

Comment: I find it very annoying when people down vote without suggestions for improving the question or an explanation as to what is wrong. It does not help improve StackOverflow as a resource to just do a drive-by down vote.

Comment: @RobertKaucher This user has been asked repeatedly to make the code in his questions reproducible. Since he is not willing to to so, he just gets a downvote from me and nothing else.

Comment: It is easy enough for you to simulate such a matrix, or illustrate the problem with a simpler matrix. The dimensions don't matter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the function you use in [aggregate](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/stats/html/aggregate.html) return more than one value. For example:

```
aggregate(corr, list(cusBREAK), function(values){ 
   c( "x"       = mean(values), 
      "pixels"  = length(values), 
      "percent" = length(values) / length(corr) * 100 
   ) 
}, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: `na.rm=TRUE` should probably be within `mean`? And it is unclear if `NA`s should be counted or not.

Comment: @ZadSim You got that because you failed to provide a reproducible example, that's why.